# Shiny DownloadHandler does not download the file

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I don't have much experience working on shiny. I am trying to download the data by using DownloadHandeler function. I get nothing when I hit the download button.

My code:

```
ui:   downloadButton('download',"Download the data"),


Server :

 output$tb_cc <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(input$dataset_cc)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(tidytext)
    
    df <- filedata_cc()
    df$date <- df$Responsedate
    df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
    df <-
      subset(df, df$date >= input$dateRange_cc[1] &
               df$date <= input$dateRange_cc[2])
    
    df <- subset(df, df$sentiment_segment == input$sentiment_cc)
    
    df <- subset(df, df$Type.1 == input$issuetype_cc)
    
    
    df<- df[c(3:10)]
    DT::datatable(df)
  })

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 'Sentiment_data.csv' }, 
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(df(), file)
    }
  )
```

sample data :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFoc4.png)

Comment: Hi, Could you edit your question to provide a minimal data set? Like they describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That would make trouble-shooting your code much easier.

Comment: This is how it looks like :

Responsedate : 06/01/2021
Market: UK
NPS : 10
Type.1 : a
concat_comment: abhs
sentiment_segment : positive

Comment: Could you tell us about 'filedata_cc()'? From which package does this function originate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `df()` reactive object outside of `renderDataTable`. Something like this should work:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   downloadButton('download',"Download the data")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df<-reactive({
    faithful
  })

  output$download <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { 'Sentiment_data.csv' },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(df(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So in your case, instead of `df<-reactive({ faithful })` in my example, you can write

```
df <- reactive({
    df<-filedata_cc()
    df$date <- df$Responsedate
    df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
    df <-
      subset(df, df$date >= input$dateRange_cc[1] &
               df$date <= input$dateRange_cc[2])
    
    df <- subset(df, df$sentiment_segment == input$sentiment_cc)
    
    df <- subset(df, df$Type.1 == input$issuetype_cc)
    
    
    df<- df[c(3:10)]
    df
})
```

Comment: I still get the error (Error - 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)).